# bundle command not found on bash script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, bundler, rvmrc

I'm wrote a script to automatically run when reboot on crontab

this is my configuration in `crontab -e`

```
@reboot /home/deploy/startup_script >> /home/deploy/startup_script.log 2>$1
```

This start the script and create logs in `/home/deploy`

Then this is the `startup_script`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Changing directory"
cd /home/deploy/source/myapp
echo $PWD

echo "Pulling Dev Branch..."
git pull origin dev_branch

echo "Running Bundle Install"
sudo gem install bundler
bundle install

echo "Deploying to Staging..."
bundle exec cap staging deploy
```

when I run this script manually using `./startup_script` it runs properly but when I run it automatically in crontab it shoes `bundle command not found` even I install the bundler already.

Here's the logs from `startup_script.log`

```
Changing directory
/home/deploy/source/myapp
Pulling Dev Branch...
From ssh://1.xx.xx.xx.io:20194/xx/myapp
 * branch            dev_branch -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Running Bundle Install
Successfully installed bundler-2.0.2
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.0.2
Done installing documentation for bundler after 5 seconds
1 gem installed
/home/deploy/startup_script: line 12: bundle: command not found
Deploying to Staging...
/home/deploy/startup_script: line 15: bundle: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

The cron often clears the whole environment, including this `$PATH` variable. Therefore, the script may behave differently in your cron compared to the behavior in the shell. To avoid having to type the absolute path to a command, shells introduced the `$PATH` environment variable, each directory is separated by a : and searches are done from left to right.

**Option I: You can use absolute path:**

Run which bundle as sudoer to get the full path for the bundle command. If the output is `/usr/bin/bundle`, your bundle command in the script would look like:

```
/usr/bin/bundle install
```

**Option II: Set the PATH variable:**

Run echo "`$PATH`" as user who runs this script to get the `$PATH` variable and make sure this variable is available in your cron script too. For example, if the output was `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`, you would put the below line in the top of your shell script:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

The environment that your crontab uses is going to be different than your regular login shell.

Now, I might be wrong about this, but I think when the crontab executes, it's not a login shell, so it doesn't have anything you've added to your path in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

The best practice here would be to use the full path of the executable for `bundle`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Redirecting `stderr` to `stdout`, there should be `2>&1`
2. Is the path where the `gem` packages are installed is added to the `$PATH` variable? Try to provide the full path to this script
3. I suggest you make an entry to see what environment variables you have for `crontab`:

   ```
   * * * * * printenv > ~/printenv.log
   ```